# compare string with Regular Expressions in if statement

Tags: bash

I have file `test.txt`

```
class c1 {
    ___________ any text _____________
}
class c2 {
    ___________ any text _____________
}
class c3 {
    ___________ any text _____________
}
```

I write bash script to scan `test.txt` line by line and compare each line with regular expressions to get the lines that contain the header of class but not work :(

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line           
do           
    if [[ "$line" =~ "class *\w+" ]]; then
        echo $line
    fi  
done <test.txt
```

The final goal separate each class in file

Comment: You mean write each class in to new file? What do you mean by separate each class in file?

Comment: @JS웃 That it I mean write each class in to new file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way with `awk`

```
awk '/^class/{p=1;++x}/^}/{p=0;print $0>"file"x}p{print $0>"file"x}' test.txt
```

**Output**

```
$ head file*
==> file1 <==
class c1 {
    ___________ any text _____________
}

==> file2 <==
class c2 {
    ___________ any text _____________
}

==> file3 <==
class c3 {
    ___________ any text _____________
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try following regex. It uses character clases instead of a literal space and `\w` to avoid the use of double quotes:

```
if [[ "$line" =~ class[[:blank:]][[:alnum:]]+ ]]; then
  ...
fi
```

---

**EDIT**: To write each class to a different file, do grouping of the class name and redirect to it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read line           
do     
    if [[ "$line" =~ class[[:blank:]]([[:alnum:]]+) ]]; then
        echo "$line" >> ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.txt
    fi  
done <test.txt
```

To check result, run:

```
head c[123].txt
```

That yields:

```
==> c1.txt <==
class c1 {

==> c2.txt <==
class c2 {

==> c3.txt <==
class c3 {
```

Comment: Thank you 
can I write regex to represent 
`calss c1 {`
`___________ any text _____________`
`}`

Comment: @motaz: Is this a question? Do you want to match it in a line?

Comment: I apologized to you
but The final goal separate each class in file 
can I do it in regex  ??

Answer (score 3):

The special regex chars must be **unquoted** (the manual says "Any part of the pattern may be quoted to force it to be matched as a string.".

Also, bash regular expressions don't understand the perl `\w`.

This works:

```
[[ $line =~ "class "[[:alnum:]_]+ ]]
```

Answer (score 2):

why not use `grep`?

```
kent$  grep -E '^class\s+\w+.*{' test 
class c1 {
class c2 {
class c3 {
```

Comment: if i use grep i can't continue to final goal separate each class in file